# Convert a MPICH2 enabled code to OpenCL code

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, opencl, mpich

I have a utility written in c++ and uses MPICH2 it do some heavy computation and I am not happy with it performance and there are many scope of improvement.

Firstly MPICH2 only uses exes, so I have to write my data to a file and pass that file as argument to that utility which again read all the data and write the output back to the file.
If I can have this in dll I can save lots of time in passing the data. Also if I can somehow run this on GPU this will give a boost (not much sure).

I am wondering how much effort will it take to convert the utility code to OpenCL or are there any tools that will do 60-70% of the conversion task.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that it will require as much work to convert the code to OpenCL as it would be to transform a comparable serial code to a parallel code.  I know of no tools that can automate the process of transforming an MPI code into an OpenCL code. I'd be very interested to learn from others on SO of any such tools.

There has been some research done, and results published, on running MPI on a GPU.  My impression is that any of this work is still research grade and probably neither reliable nor portable.

Finally, though it won't help use your GPU, why not correct the faults with your MPI code ?  I'm a little unclear, but it seems that one of the problems is that your MPI code writes and reads files as a way of passing data around.  This is not a necessary feature of MPI programs and could be revised

Comment: +1; stop using file I/O as a communications medium.   But also, MPI and OpenCL are orthogonal; one is for speeding up computations by communicating parts of the problem between nodes (or processors on a node) and one is for accelerating computation on a node.   There's no reason for things to be one or the other.

Comment: I can remove reads and write just passing the buffer address and utility can update the data and I can then get the results.But for that I have to convert utility exe to dll but MPICH2 doesn't work with      dlls.

Comment: There's no problem linking in other libraries (eg, dlls) with mpi, or mpich2 for that matter, so it's not at all clear what you're asking.

Comment: I have asked a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066143/using-mpich2-with-regular-dll but not get any response.

Comment: Did you get the question in above comment link?